# Magento 2: Is there a way to check what is current page

Tags: magento2

In my case. i visited to checkout page and logined. How to check current page is checkout and redirect back to it! Tried

```
   if($this->session->getCurrentPage() == 'checkout') {
        return $store->getUrl('checkout');
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance(); 
$urlInterface=$objectManager->create('Magento\Framework\UrlInterface');

echo $urlInterface->getCurrentUrl();
```

Comment: if need echo $urlInterface->getUrl()

Answer (score 2):

Set block content with custom function :

```
protected $_request;

public function __construct(
    ...
    \Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http $request,
    ...
) {
    ...
    $this->_request = $request;
    ...
}

public function isHomepage()
{

    if ($this->_request->getFullActionName() == 'cms_index_index') {//cms_index_index your page identifier e.g. 'checkout_index_index' for checkout
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Template code :

```
<?php  $isHome = $block->isHomepage(); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$this->getUrl('*/*/*', ['_current' => true, '_use_rewrite' => true])
```